# display bootstrap on top of screen, not on top of page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a very long page and when I open a bootstrap modal from the bottom of this page the modal is displayed on top of page not on top of the screen. So the user has to scroll up in order to see the modal.

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: can you add your code. because your question is very vague unless i can see your code

Comment: Your modal must not have `position:fixed` & `top:0;`. Also please post what have you tried and try replicating your issue here with some code, to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

You have got the result after adding below style sheet in your css.

```
yourselector {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
```